# How do I interpret the includedQuantity in Azure's rate card API?

Tags: azure, billing

I am trying to calculate the cost incurred on my Azure Pay-As-You-Go subscription using the usage and rate-card API's. For this I came across this parameter `includedQuantity` in the rate-card API's which, according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt219004.aspx), refers to "The resource quantity that is included in the offer at no cost. Consumption beyond this quantity will be charged."

Consider an example, where the usageQuantity is 700 and the rate-card is as follows:

```
0 : 20
101 : 15
501 : 10
```

and the `includedQuantity` is 200.

My assumption was, the calculation would be as one of the following:

1. `Quantity = (700 - 200) = 500`
   Hence, `cost = 100 * 20 + 400 * 15 = 8000`
2. New rate card:

`0 : 0
101 : 0
201 : 15
501 : 10`

So, `cost = 300 * 15 + 200 * 10 = 6500`

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908992/billing-calculation-of-rates), but it does not clarify the `includedQuantity` properly.

Answer (score -1):

Great question! So I checked with Azure Billing team on this and what they told me is that they will first take off the included units (200 in your example) and then apply graduated pricing on the remaining units.

Based on this, your cost would be `4500`:

`Total units consumed: 700
Included units: 200
Tiered pricing: {0-100 = 0; 101-200 = 0; 201-500=15; 501-No Upper Limit=10}`

`4500 = 0 x 100 + 0 x 100 + 15 x 300`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `6500 = 0 x 100 + 0 x 100 + 15 x 300 + 10 x 200` Your math only pays for 300 consumed quantity and not 500.

Comment: @JohnSmith Above calculation is based on the assumption that pricing calculation will be based on 500 units (700 units consumed - 200 included units) (100 + 100 + 300). With your calculation, you are calculating on all 700 units (100 + 100 + 300 + 200).

Comment: why are the 100 + 100 free then? according to the meter rates they should cost 20 and 15. In the calculation you substract the included quantity and then ALSO pay 0 for the first 200 quantity. I don't think that can be right. This would mean for each includedQuanitty you basically get double that for free.

Comment: That was my question to Billing team as well :).

Comment: I see... Is there any chance of some official documentation being made for this? Because as it stands it's almost impossible to calculate your cost accuratly